# Columns invalid (suddenly) in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

While I'm relatively new to SQL Server, I've been working with the SQL language and databases for over two decades, and I've got a real noodle scratcher.

A stored procedure that had been working fine for years suddenly stopped working.  The procedure used a series of Insert Into #TempTables that were references further down in the procedure.  Again, for years, this worked fine.  Then suddenly, the other day, we started getting invalid column errors on the last couple of queries based on temp tables created before it.  I know SQL doesn't necessarily run procedurally, but this query ran reliable just fine before now, so something strange is afoot.

Now, if I run each query of the procedure individually in order, I'm able run the entire procedure without error - it was only when the procedure was called from the front end (or when debugging a different procedure that called the offending procedure) that the error would occur.

After a quick search, I concluded that the best solution would be to do away with the temp tables, and simply nest the queries as sub queries in the "From" expression, eliminating the procedural nature of the procedure.  Once I did that, the procedure ran fine.

But my question is - why would something that worked fine for ages suddenly stop working?  This is what is troubling me, and more importantly, my boss.

There were no updates made to SQL Server around the time the procedure stopped working, so I don't think it's related to that.  And while there has been additional data added, I'm still hard-pressed to believe that we broke that camel's back where the procedure suddenly stopped working.  (I confirmed this by running the procedure on a restored version of the data from the last time it ran successfully; the procedure still errored out.)

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Just for testing purposes....copy the create procedure script somewhere...delete the stored procedure, recreate it from the sql script....

Comment: Does the procedure create the temp table then alter it to add the columns that it was complaining about? Or alternatively is the stored procedure called from some other batch or stored proc that can create a temp table of the same name?

Comment: Temp tables with identical names but different schemas created in your procedure and in the calling one? Plausible, if you don't create / drop temp tables explicitly everywhere before / after using them.